# Avoid unselect behavior on c3js graph

Tags: javascript, json, c3.js

i'm creating a line chart with data points, each data point should have a different style depending of the data, i'm achieving this using the select API that you made available to us
as shown in this example [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/jrdsxvys/7/)
the thing is that, the user can select and unselect other points, and i want to avoid this behavior
is that even posible?

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
            ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
        ],
        selection: {
            enabled: true
        }
    },
    point: {
        focus: {
            expand: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    }
});
chart.select(['data1'], [1, 3, 5]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is lock the points in their current expanded/unexpanded states add

```
chart.internal.config.data_selection_enabled = false;
```

after your chart.select call

http://jsfiddle.net/jrdsxvys/316/